# Gmt php or UTC C# equivalence through SOAP

Tags: c#, php, .net, utc, gmt

is C# `DateTime.UtcNow`  and php `date("c")` are equivalent

I doubt because when I soap both I get from

C# :

```
<dateDebutAction xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2012-03-20T16:01:28.3954818Z</dateDebutAction>
```

and from
PHP :

```
<dateDebutAction xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2012-03-20T16:04:29+00:00</dateDebutAction>
```

if they are not equivalent what is the C# for date("c")

**context :**
I send the first soap to someone who work in PHP, and he's saying me the date is not valid, he gave me an exemple in php with date("c") and it work.
So I wonder if my code is wrong.

I filter the soap request with mssoapt and the two request are equals except the datetime.

Comment: Those look equivalent to me. UTC and GMT are not exactly the same thing, but the differences don't matter here. The C# code uses higher precision and a different way of expressing a `0` offset.

Comment: could this different way of expressing a 0 offset is known as pb with webservices treatment

Comment: These look like equivalent ISO 8601 dates to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Z` means Zulu time, which is equivalent to `GMT+00:00`.

> The UTC time zone is sometimes denoted by the letter Z—a reference to
>   the equivalent nautical time zone (GMT), which has been denoted by a Z
>   since about 1950.

*Reference:* [Wikipedia–Time zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones)

Comment: ok this is not the pb, I wanna know if it's possible to get 2012-03-20T16:04:29+00:00 in the soap from C#

Comment: @ChristopheDebove, You can use `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00` string format.

Comment: My C# proxy class( the web reference) is waiting a DateTime not a string

Comment: @ChristopheDebove, What technology are you using? WCF?

Comment: i'm in console project for the test but after I'm in monorail project both are webreference or servicereference (same result).

Comment: @ChristopheDebove, As I know, you can't specify format during serialization. One possible solution is to customize your data contract and send datetime as string.